Mouse on Windows 10, it loses element when I drag
Windows 10. Higher end Logitech mouse. Have no issues with left or right click. But when I for example drag item in Outlook to a folder, or even icon on desktop, it loses it's "hold" and let's go before I release the button. So sometimes it drops items to wrong folder etc. I used same mouse in Windows 7 Pro and didn't have issues. I am almost convinced that it has something to do with Windows 10.

When I had this problem with a similar mouse. There was dirt in the clicker, cleaning it might resolve the issue for awhile, but a new mouse ultimately is the solution. This is a hardware problem it software

It could be that changing drag/drop sensitivity might help: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-drag-and-drop-sensitivity-in-windows-11.19652/, or it could be bad switch, as mentioned. Also, if not using touchpad, you might disable it, lest it interfere with drag/drop: https://www.makeuseof.com/ways-to-disable-touchpad-in-windows-10/

I don't think there is any dirt, it's clean.
The item drops while dragging before I release the button.
I don't think I'm touching the touchpad while dragging, or you are saying it can still interfere even if not touched? I'd rather leave it on, sometimes use that when traveling and no room for mouse.

You can configure a Windows 10 computer to disable the touchpad only when a mouse is plugged into a USB port.
